# How to add new attribute to header section in soapui using groovy script?

Tags: xml, groovy, attributes, soapui, addition

I need to add new attribute to header section. I have an example of soapui request

`<request> <header timeout="?" subver="?"> <msgId>...</msgId> </header>`

In header section there are two attributes: "timeout" and "subver" and I need add the new one i.e. "howToAddNewOne".

```
<header timeout="?" subver="?" howToAddNewOne="?">
```

**I will be very gratefull for solution in groovy :)
**
I tried something like this but didn't work :(

`getXML = new GroovyUtils(context) xmlRequest = getXML.getXmlHolder("req#Request") newAttr = xmlRequest.put('//header/@howToAddNewOne', 'value')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `XmlSlurper` and `StreamingMarkupBuilder`:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

def input = '''<request><header timeout="?" subver="?"><msgId></msgId></header></request>'''
def request = new XmlSlurper().parseText(input)

// add new attribute to <header> tag
request.header.@howToAddNewOne = "?"

// get the modified XML and check that it worked
def outputBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
String updatedXml = outputBuilder.bind{ mkp.yield request }
assert updatedXml.contains("howToAddNewOne")
println(updatedXml)
```

Output:

```
<request><header howToAddNewOne='?' timeout='?' subver='?'><msgId></msgId></header></request>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint.
It is true that I did not use it in 100%, but it directed me to a solution that worked.
Since I am using GroovyUtils I wrote something like this:

```
getXML = new GroovyUtils(context)
getReq = getXML.getXmlHolder("req#Request")
header = getReq.getDomNode('//header')
attr = header.getAttributes()
doc = header.getOwnerDocument()
newAttr = doc.createAttribute('howToAddNewOne')
newAttr.setNodeValue('howToAddNewOne')
attr.setNamedItem(newAttr)
```

Thanks a lot :)
Have a nice day!!!